# email_from in Email Template Ignored Odoo

Tags: email, odoo, email-templates

I was just looking for the functionality wherein I would be able to send email from the individual user account. For the purpose I set the email_from field properly for the email template properly in case of Sales Order.

Now when I am sending the email from Sales Order I am still receiving the mail from Outgoing Email Server Email ID. Although when I checked my messaged the email_from field was populated with the right email ID. Even then when i receive mail in my inbox the email is sent from Outgoing Email Server Email ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]            You can not set an email ID like "abc@xyz.com" in that field. That field is set through expression like

```
${(object.user_id.email or '')|safe}
```

So you must set this thing properly >> object.user_id.email

Set your desired email address on "Email" field here.

For setting this Go to "Preferences".